# What's involved in accepting payments online?

Tags: e-commerce, currency

I was going to write an online ordering system for a small deli, and was wondering what's involved in accepting plastic payments online.

Both the deli, and it's customers are in the U.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the deli already takes credit cards, you should contact their credit card processor and see if they have a internet payment gateway (and library/API).

If not, you need a Merchant account at the bank and a Credit Card processor that provides the gateway and API.

**Edit:** Other options would also be to go with PayPal or Google Checkout integration.

Answer (score 2):

Check out

Paypal for the easiest integration  https://merchant.paypal.com/cgi-bin/marketingweb?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=merchant/wp_standard

or

Authorize.net for a custom implementation / lower fees etc
http://developer.authorize.net/